# randomizing list and exporting the results as unique set of 4 strings

Tags: python, python-3.x, random, set

I have wanted to randomize list of strings, 9 different strings and then printing out the strings into unique set of four then exporting it into txt file. Here is what I have tried so far, but I am not sure how to set them into groups of four.

```
import random
a = "0xa5"
b = "0x1"
c = "0xE5924"
d = "0xE59"
e = "0xC60aE"
g = "0xd7F1DF"
h = "0xDEF1717"
i = "0xA102072A4C07F9"
j = "0x934A0E2c6C427D9F25"



my_list = [a,b,c,d,e,g,h,i,j]
random.shuffle(my_list)
myset = set(my_list)
print(myset)
```

I want the print outcome to come out in an example of:

```
["0xa5","0x1","0xE5924","0xE59"],
["0xa5","0x1","0xE5924","0xA102072A4C07F9"],
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it with a while loop, just picking random numbers of the set you get.

```
oldarray= my_list
newarray=[]
count=0
while count<4:
    num=random.randint(0,8)
    newarray.append(oldarray[num])
    count+=1
print(newarray)
```

Answer (score -1):

```py
import random
a = "0xa5"
b = "0x1"
c = "0xE5924"
d = "0xE59"
e = "0xC60aE"
g = "0xd7F1DF"
h = "0xDEF1717"
i = "0xA102072A4C07F9"
j = "0x934A0E2c6C427D9F25"
sample = random.sample([a,b,c,d,e,g,h,i,j],4)
sample.sort()
print(sample)
```

Comment: Imho `random.sample([a, b, c, d, e, g, h, i, j], 4)` would already do the job: `random.sample` samples _without_ replacement, so you already get a list of unique items.

Comment: Absolutely, and `set()` was added here not to make the sample represent only unique strings, but as a way to **sort** them. :-). `random.sample()` returns a sample in a so to say random order. It can return first `[a, b, c, d]` and then `[b, d, c, a]`.

Comment: Yes to the order re. `random.sample`. But `set()` doesn't sort anything either -- quite the opposite? (Does op really want a sorted list?)

Comment: `set()` sorts things weirdly according to the order of its hashes, but does sort. The construct `list(set([whatever content in a arbitrary order]))` will return a list with the same order each time.

Comment: `list(set([]))` is slower than `[].sort()`, but `.sort()` requires a separate line of code, and I wanted to keep everything in one line :-)

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood your second last comment, but look at `print(list(set([-1, -2])) == list(set([-2, -1])))`? (Insertion order matters.)

Comment: @Timus, I agree: the trick doesn't work all the time. Thanks) `.sort()` is better.

Comment: If you wanted to sort in the same line, why didn't you use `sorted`? I see zero indication that you're supposed to sort, though.

Comment: @KellyBundy, regarding `sorted` a good point. What concerns the *indications*, actually there was one. The OP wrote "unique set". A set doesn't have an order, as we all know.

Comment: I think there was some problem with the variables, when i generated with for loops it gave me lists of three, somewhere in 50 in 1. Since it was only couple, I hand picked them away.